# Selection Sort (low to high) python

Tags: python, sorting, select

I am trying to write a selection sort algorithm for sorting lists of numbers from lowest to highest.

```
def sortlh(numList):
    if type(numList) != list:
        print("Input must be a list of numbers.")
    else:
        inf = float("inf")
        sortList = [0]*len(numList)
        count = 0
        while count < len(numList):          
            index = 0
            indexLowest = 0
            lowest = numList[index]
            while index < (len(numList) - 1):
                if numList[index + 1] < numList[index]:
                    lowest = numList[index + 1]
                    indexLowest = index + 1
                    index = index + 1
                else:
                    index = index + 1
            sortList[count] = lowest
            numList[indexLowest] = inf
            count = count + 1
    return sortList
```

When I run this code on:

```
sortlh([9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1])
```

I get (as expected):

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

However, when I try another example, I get:

```
sortlh([1,3,2,4,5,7,6,9,8])
```

[8, 6, 9, 2, 4, 5, 7, 1, 3]

Does anyone see what is going on here?

Comment: Why are you doing this? If its for anything other than trying to improve your skills you should look [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted), the docs for the builtin ```sorted()``` function.

Comment: As a side note, the kind of type-checking you do up top is usually not helpful. In this case, your code would have already raised a nice `TypeError` explaining that `numList` isn't iterable, but instead you're making it print some output with less information and return `None`, and meanwhile you're excluding all other types of sequences (even subclasses of `list`) for no good reason.

Comment: Also, instead of "pre-filling" `sortList`, why not just do `sortList = []`, then `sortList.append(lowest)`, and `while len(sortList) < len(numList)`, eliminating `count` entirely?

Comment: @wnnmaw Yeah, I know there is an equivalent function in the standard library, just trying to improve skills. Thanks.

Comment: Finally, it would really help to either some `print`s (e.g., start with `print('found {} at #{} of {}'.format(lowest, indexLowest, numList))`, then see where that goes wrong and add some intermediate `print`s to narrow it down), and/or run it through a debugger or a visualizer like [this one](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display) to trace through it until it goes wrong.

Comment: @abarnert The type-check isn't helpful, I know. The idea came to me that I hadn't done type checking before came to me and I figured I would test that out. As for your second suggestion though, initializing sortList as sortList = [], I tried that the other day with another list and then, when I tried to fill the list with the appropriate values I got an out of bounds error? I know you can initialize arrays like this in other languages but I had issues with python.

Comment: When you do `lst = []` you have an empty list.  Trying to access it with any index will give an out of bounds error.  But you can then do `lst.append()` and that works fine.

Comment: In case you're curious, I have a moderately large collection of sorts in Python and/or Cython at http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~dstromberg/sort-comparison/

Comment: @JP1992: When I say "why not just do `sortList = []`, then `sortList.append(lowest)` …", you have to do the `sortList.append(lowest)` part too. Just taking half of my comment and ignoring the other half isn't going to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would suggest rewriting your program.

```
def sortlh(lst_input):
    lst = list(lst_input) # make a copy of lst_input
    i = 0
    while i < len(lst):
        j = i + 1
        i_lowest = i
        lowest = lst[i_lowest]
        while j < len(lst):
            if lst[j] < lowest:
                i_lowest = j
                lowest = lst[i_lowest]
            j += 1
        lst[i], lst[i_lowest] = lst[i_lowest], lst[i]  # swap
        i += 1
    return lst

test = [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
assert sortlh(test) == sorted(test)
test = [1,3,2,4,5,7,6,9,8]
assert sortlh(test) == sorted(test)
```

- We don't test the type of the input.  Anything that acts like a list will work, and even an iterator will work.
- We don't "mutate" the original input list.  We only work on a copy of the data.
- When we find the lowest number, we swap it with the first number, and then only look at the remaining numbers.  Thus we have less work to do on each loop as we have fewer and fewer unsorted numbers.

EDIT:

If you are a beginner, this part might seem too tricky.  If it confuses you or you don't like it, just ignore it for now.

This is a more-advanced way to solve this problem in Python.  The inner loop simply finds the lowest number and the index of the lowest number.  We can use the Python built-in function `min()` to do this!

We build a "generator expression" that loops over the list, yielding up tuples.  Each tuple is the number and its position.  Since we want lower numbers to sort lower, we put the number first in the tuple so that `min()` can properly compare the tuples.  Then `min()` will find the lowest tuple and we get the value and index.

Also, the outer loop is now a `for` loop with `enumerate` rather than a `while` loop using indexing.

```
def sortlh(lst_input):
    lst = list(lst_input) # make a copy of lst_input
    for i, x in enumerate(lst):
        lowest, i_lowest = min((n, j) for j, n in enumerate(lst) if j >= i)
        lst[i], lst[i_lowest] = lst[i_lowest], lst[i]  # swap
    return lst

test = [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
assert sortlh(test) == sorted(test)
test = [1,3,2,4,5,7,6,9,8]
assert sortlh(test) == sorted(test)
```